# Find values of All Parent Tags in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML structure like below and need to create a string with value of all parent tags :

STRING : `/Root/Upload/ORTHO`

[image]

Although HTML strcuture is bit weired here :

```
    <div id="treeview-container">
   <ul class="treeview">
      <li class="contains-items items-expanded">
         Root
         <ul style="">
            <li class="contains-items">
               JACK
               <ul style="display: none;" class="notselected"></ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contains-items items-expanded">
               Upload
               <ul style="display: block;">
                  <li class="contains-items items-expanded selected">
                     ORTHO
                     <ul style="display: block;" class="notselected"></ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="contains-items">
                     BEAST
                     <ul style="display: none;"></ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contains-items items-expanded">
               JANE
               <ul style=""></ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contains-items">
               MIKE
               <ul style="display: none;"></ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I tried something like :

```
var parentEls = $(".selected").parentsUntil( "#treeview-container")
              .map(function(){
                   return this.textContent;
               }).get().join( "/" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it will not work. By definition the `.text()` function returns all the text inside an element. So for example for the `UPLOAD` node, it  will return `UPLOAD ORTHO BEAST` (all within the same `li` element)  instead of `UPLOAD`.

A solution is to modify your HTML code and add `id="node_name"` attribute for each node, just like this :

```
<div id="treeview-container">
<ul class="treeview">
  <li id="Root" class="contains-items items-expanded">
     Root
     <ul style="">
        <li id="Jack" class="contains-items">
           JACK
           <ul style="display: none;" class="notselected"></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="Upload" class="contains-items items-expanded">
           Upload
           <ul style="display: block;">
              <li id="ORTHO" class="contains-items items-expanded selected">
                 ORTHO
                 <ul style="display: block;" class="notselected"></ul>
              </li>
              <li id="BEAST" class="contains-items">
                 BEAST
                 <ul style="display: none;"></ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="JANE" class="contains-items items-expanded">
           JANE
           <ul style=""></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="MIKE" class="contains-items">
           MIKE
           <ul style="display: none;"></ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

And use this code, it will work :

```
 var parentEls = $(".selected").parentsUntil( "#treeview-container")
                               .andSelf() //to get the current node appear in the path
                               .map(function(){
                                   return $(this).attr("id");
                               }).get().join( "/" );
```

See this [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lau658m2/)

If you don't want to modify your HTML code, you could use javascript to get only the text of the selected element and ignoring all the text of child elements. Just modify the code given before, replace this line :

```
return $(this).attr("id");
```

By this one :

```
return $(this).clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text();
```

Clone the element that you want text of, then remove all the child elements from this cloned element and then returns the text of element.